# Using Deployment Slots, I mixed up my Connection Strings, how can I get it to work?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am half expecting the answer to be delete everything and start over, but I figured I'd come here first after not figuring it out / finding an answer.

I created a Web App, and two deployment slots (staging / development). I created two DB's (DBName, DBName_Development). I forgot to tick off "Slot Setting" on the Development slot, and when I swapped it to Staging the configuration setting swapped as well. No problem, I figured, I will just put in the correct configuration setting and then tick off all the "Slot Setting" boxes so this doesn't occur again.

However, even after doing that, it appears my Staging site is still looking for the old DBName_Development database. Since it was changed it's not working. Not sure if I can even access the web.config for the staging site.

So, do I just trash everything and start over? Or am I missing some setting somewhere in the blades of Azure? I tried Restarting the Web App to no avail.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions/guidance/help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may start from Kudu console - it is the nice tooling for getting different things done with your web app.

So, if you suspect that some of your websites use something wrong or things mixed, you may go to the http://webappname1.scm.azurewebsites.net (note .scm.) and http://webappname2.scm.azurewebsites.net and compare the needed settings. If you will see that there is nothing wrong (or, vice versa, something is wrong), then you may proceed to the debug console and check the state of your web.config. And replace it if you will see that it will be needed.